# Create Stack in C++ with Push, Pop etc

Tags: c++, list, stack

We are trying to create a C++ program that works like a stack.
The following instructions are given:
There should be several methods:

We have to use this definition of the `StackElement`:

```
struct StackElement {
int digit;
StackElement* predecessor;
};
```

The problem now is how to create the `push`-function without an next parameter as there was with ordinary lists. The same for the pop function.
We accomplished to get `push()` create a new StackElement and `pop()` delete the new Element, but with 2 new Elements, those methods aren't working properly.

Global parameter `stack0`:

```
StackElement *stack0 = new StackElement;
```

This is the code for the `push`-function:

```
StackElement push(int z){
    StackElement *stack1 = new StackElement;
    stack1->digit = z;
    stack1->predecessor = NULL;
    stack0->predecessor = stack1;
    stack1 = stack0;
```

This is the `pop()` method:

```
void pop(){
    StackElement *stack1 = new StackElement;
    if (stack0!=NULL){
    stack1->digit = 0;
    stack0->predecessor = NULL; //predecessor = NULL;
    }
}
```

And finally the `main` method:

```
int main()
{
    int z;
    create();

    cout << "Which number to the stack?" << endl;
    cin >> z;

    push(z);
    pop();
    print();

    return 0;
}
```

We thought about creating a new StackElement, that would work as a 'pseudo'-StackElement and would always stay on top so that the 'real' element on the top would always be the predecessor of the pseudo-Element - but we think this would be against how the stack should work.

So do you guys have any clues on how to proceed? Is there something we are just missing?

Comment: Why is `pop` a `void`function? I would expect it to return the `int`...

Comment: `stack1 = stack0;` is definitely does not make sense. stack1 is a local variable in your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st) Why not using [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)?

2nd) Stack should be [LIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_%28computing%29). That means your stack0 should always be the newest one... This leads to:

```
StackElement* stack0 = NULL;       // until C++11
// StackElement* stack0 = nullptr; // since C++11

void push(int z) {
  StackElement *stack1 = new StackElement;
  stack1->digit = z;
  stack1->predecessor = stack0;
  stack0 = stack1;
}

void pop() {
  if(stack0) {
    StackElement *tmp = stack0;
    stack0 = stack0->predecessor;
    delete tmp;
  }
}
```

You don't need the allocate a new one in the pop function. This will end in a huge memory leak.

What you meant by pseudo is called root element and is sometimes used in sequences. But not necessary here, since stack0 is the root or in this case the end (the first element and the end).

A better approach would be to encapsulate it in a class as ryrich mentioned in his answer. And the best approach would be using the C++-given [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem just fine. And also thanks for the 'root-element' explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track here. To keep track of your elements, you need a class. Something like:

```
class Stack{
private:
  StackElement *last_data, *first_data;

public:
  Stack():last_data(NULL), first_data(NULL){}  
  void push(int digit);
  void pop();
};
```

Have the push/pop functions part of the `Stack` class. For example, push:

```
void Stack::push(int digit)
{
  StackElement *p=new StackElement();
  p->digit = digit;
  if(last_data)
    p->predecessor=last_data;
  else // empty stack
  {
    p->predecessor=NULL;
    first_data = p;
  }
  last_data=p;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: I'll add pop function for completeness:

```
void Stack::pop()
{
  if (last_data)
  {
    StackElement *tp = last_data;
    last_data = last_data->predecessor;
    delete tp;
  }
}
```

Comment: you have several errors: 1. `first_data(NULL)` first_data is not a pointer. 2. you are pushing at back, but popping at front, this meant to be fifo, but stack's usualy are lifo.

Comment: not sure what you mean there. running this code shows no issues.

Answer (score 0):

if the stack is full and we try to put something in it then it will give us the error of stack overflow

```
void IntStack::push()
{
   clrscr();
   int num;
   if(top>=stackSize)
        cout<<"stack Overflow"<<endl;
   else
   {
    cout<<"Enter Number=";
    cin>>num;
    top++;
      stackArray[top]=num;
   }
}
```